# A word for storing pre calculated-constructed data

Tags: meaning

I precalculate data and store it in a static table and call this process 'caching' but that doesn't seem correct based on a quick dictionary search (hiding, concealing)  I'm just saving the data statically to avoid the process time to make the calculation.  Is there a more appropriate term/word?

Comment: I voted to close because I think you would get better help from Programmers or StackOverflow.  They would probably know what the usual lingo is.

Comment: @KitFox, yep, quick response in Programmers, thx

Comment: You can provide the link to your post on programmersSE.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/146336/a-word-for-storing-pre-calculated-constructed-data

Answer (score 2):

The generic term *[initialization](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/initialization)*, "The process of preparing something to begin" or "An assignment of an initial value for a data object or variable" is often used for such activity.  The terms *[precalculate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/precalculate)* ("To calculate in advance") and *[precalculation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/precalculation)* ("A calculation performed in advance") also are perfectly adequate, even if the pre-calculation program stores the data into a file rather than handing it off directly to the program that consumes it.  Also, *pre-generate* and *pre-generation* apparently are used [quite commonly](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&hl=en&q=%22pre-generate%22&oq=%22pre-generate%22&aq=f&aqi=g2g-v6g-C1&aql=&gs_nf=1&gs_l=serp.3..0l2j0i15l6j0i33.115093.116892.0.117530.2.2.0.0.0.0.281.524.2-2.2.0.Od9m7iJYHZ8).

Answer (score 2):

You could call it ***buffering***. Typically, data that is pre-fetched is *buffered* until actual processing takes place.

At the same time, 'cache' is not wrong. It is recognized in CS as (a small local) storage for near-instant access.

Answer (score 1):

You could say you're populating the table.